# How to count rest method calls/invokes

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

Is there any way to count each time rest method beeing called? I know we can do this by calling something like [Singleton class].counter("method name");
but this way forces me to modify each @Path on my server, where I have houndreds of them right now.
I read something about Interceptors, but don't know If this is it.

Comment: Have a look at servlet filters http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for :), very helpfull link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-writing-filters.htm
Unfortunately I cannot give you +1 and correct answer. Too low reputation.

Comment: no worries, glad I could help :)